# What kind of shiny bronze beetle is this?

Tags: species-identification

[image][image]

Lots of these on my rosemary bush

About 7mm long

Comment: Please provide your location. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The plant helped identifying the beetle: This is a rosemary beetle (*Chrysolina americana*), which feeds on rosemary,  lavender and thyme. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysolina_americana) and [here](https://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/rosemary-beetle) for some more information.

[image]